# ZF2 custom methods in view model available to specific template

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Can't find any reasonable answers anywhere on this.

In a controller, you return an instance of `ViewModel` which can have child ViewModel's included. That's fine, i get it, but these children blocks need variables also, which you can set right there in the same controller action. But how do you avoid 11 page long controller actions exactly?

In Magento for example, view scripts derive from "blocks" which are classes with specific methods to alter the view, so you can simply get the child html and it will handle itself independently using its own methods.

Practical (template method):

```
<?php echo $this->getSidebar(); ?>
```

Impractical (ZF2 controller):

```
$leftSidebar = new ViewModel(...
$leftSidebarPostsWidget = new ViewModel(...
$leftSidebar->addChild($leftSidebarPostsWidget);
$view = new ViewModel();
$view->addChild($leftSidebar);    

return $view;
```

I looked into view helpers but those seem to be available to all view scripts which is unnecessary.

Is there some way to associate custom render classes with specific templates?

I could just create block classes that extend ViewModel, but i'm afraid i'm just missing something useful in Zend Framework 2.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/

Comment: Perhaps use the `partial` view helper and pass it an object (using `setObjectKey()`) which contains your 'block' like methods? https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#partial-helper

Answer (score 2):

I'm totally agree with Marshall House. I developed several magento modules and the block solution is really handy.

What I did to get a similar functionality in Zend2 is to set a variable in the ViewModel named lets say 'me' that contains an object with the desired methods. In my case actually the object contains the ViewModel, and with a little work you can make a tree just the same as magento works.

```
$blockModel->setVariable('me', $blockModel);
```

The $blockModel itself has a property that holds the viewModel, and if you build a tree where

```
$blockModel->getParent();
```

returns the parent block, you could say:

```
$blockModel->getParent()->getViewModel()->addChild($blockModel->getViewModel());
```

in your phtml template, you just call`$this->me->anyMethod()` and will work.

of course is tricky but magento wasn't build in one day...